# What is wrong with this isomorphism preserving transformation to a graph of bounded clique width and bounded rank width?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, isomorphism-testing

Got an isomorphism preserving transformation to a graph of bounded
clique width and rank width. It, a paper and graphclasses.org imply
graph isomorphism is in P, so likely something is wrong.

Let $G$ be simple connected graph of order $n$ and $n>2$.

Consider the following isomorphism preserving transformation $G \to G'$.

Initially the vertices of $G'$ are $V_1=V(G) \times V(G)=\{(v_i,v_j)| v_i \in V(G),v_j \in V(G) \}$.

Make a clique of $V_1$.

For all edges $(u,v) \in E(G)$ add vertices $A_{u,v},A_{v,u}$ and call these vertices $A$ vertices. Add edges $(A_{u,v},(u,v))$ and $A_{v,u},(v,u))$.

All $A$ vertices are degree one and are adjacent to exactly one $V_1$ vertex.

In an edge $(A_{u,v},(u,v))$, the $V_1$ vertex $(u,v)$ corresponds to the edge $(u,v)$ in $E(G)$.

Given $G'$, we can recover $G$. Take all neighbors of the degree
one $A$ vertices $(u_1,v_1),(v_1,u_1),\ldots (v_n,u_n)$. These
are exactly the undirected edges of $G$, where an edge is given as
both $(u,v)$ and $(v,u)$.

So $G \cong H \iff G' \cong H'$ and the transformation is isomorphism
preserving.

$|V(G')|=n^2+2|E(G)|=O(n^2)$.

According to [graphclasses](http://graphclasses.org/classes/AUTO_738.html)
the class $(C_{n+4},gem)$-free is of bounded clique width and bounded
rank width. This class are the graphs which don't have induced subgraph
"gem" and induced cycle of length at least $4$.

We claim that for all $G$, $G'$ is in this class.

Since the $A$ vertices are of degree one, they can't be in a cycle.

This leaves only the clique $V_1$ and four or more vertices in it
induce $K_4$ as subgraph, which kills induced cycles.

The gem graph is on 5 vertices:

[image: gem graph]

Since it doesn't have degree one vertex, there are no $A$ vertices
and it is not induced subgraph of the clique.

Experiments in Sage suggest both recovering the original graph
and $G'$ is in the bounded class.

According to [Isomorphism Testing for Graphs of Bounded Rank Width](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.03737)

> We give an algorithm that, for every fixed $k$, decides isomorphism of graphs of rank width at most $k$ in polynomial time. As the clique width of a graph is bounded in terms of its rank width, we also obtain a polynomial time isomorphism test for graph classes of bounded clique width.

So the transformation, the paper and graphclass.org imply graph isomorphism is in P.

> What is wrong with the argument that graph isomorphism is in P?

Sage implementation:

```
def graphtoedgeclique2(g,adc=False):
    """
    graph to edge clique 2
    """
    ve=list(g.vertices())
    E=[]
    l=[]
    for u,v in cartesian_product_iterator([ve]*2):
        l += [(u,v)]
    E += listtoclique(l)    
    EC=[]
    for u,v in g.edges(labels=0):
        e1=('a',u,v)
        E += [(e1,(u,v))]
        e2=('a,',v,u)
        E += [(e2,(v,u))]
        EC += [e1,e2]
    G=Graph(E)
    return G

def edgeclique2tooriginal(g):
    """
    reverse edgeclique2:
    edgeclique2tooriginal(graphtoedgeclique2(g))=g
    """
    ve=[v for v in g.vertices() if g.degree(v)==1]
    E=[]
    for v in ve:
        ne=g.neighbors(v)
        assert len(ne)==1
        E += ne
    G=Graph(E,multiedges=False)
    return G

def listtoclique(l):
    E=[]
    n=len(l)
    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(i+1,n):
            E += [(l[i],l[j])]
    return E
```

Comment: Your transformation does not preserve isomorphism. Every pair of graphs with the same number of vertices and edges will have isomorphic images under your transformation.

Comment: @DavidHackenger Many thanks! You gave counterexample at least.